# python regex assign and use in if condition at the same line

Tags: python, regex

While parsing lines I am using regex. I assign the `re.search` to a variable and then perform a conditional check on it.

```
x=re.search(....)
if x:
```

Is there a way to do the search and if condition in the same line?

Thanks!

Comment: can you elaborate on the text you want to use it to find?  Like give an example of the string your searching through, then provide an example what you'd expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (re.search(...)):
```

Doesn't this option work?
If you need to work with x further, use `:=`